# Fill data in a dropdown list with mysql table in aspx vb using a class

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to load a dropdown list linked to a table in mysql in a webform asp.net in vb. I'm using a class with the following code:

```
Public Class ClCountries
    Public Function Read(ByVal Opcion As Integer) As DataTable

        Dim cnn As New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cnnPortalSmart").ConnectionString)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Try
            Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("PA_COUNTRIES_SELECT", cnn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Opcion", Opcion)

            cnn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges)
            cnn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim msgError As String
            msgError = ex.Message.ToString()
            cnn.Close()
        End Try
        Return dt
    End Function
End Class
```

It's called from Page_Load() via this method:

```
Sub LoadCountries()
    Try 
        Dim dv As New DataView(New ClCountries().Read(1)) 
        ddlCountry.DataSource = dv 
        ddlCountry.DataTextField = "Name" 
        ddlCountry.DataValueField = "ID" 
        ddlCountry.DataBind() 
        Dim li As New ListItem("Select Country", "0") 
        ddlCountry.Items.Insert(0, li) 
    Catch ex As Exception 
    End Try 
End Sub
```

The connecction string in the aspx :

```
<connectionStrings>    
    <add name="cnnPortalSmart" connectionString="Data Source=IP_NUMBER;Initial Catalog=SCHEMA_NAME; User ID=root;Password=XXXX;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />  
</connectionStrings>
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is the question? any issues? any exceptions?

Comment: What problems are you having with this code? What doesn't work? There are things I might do differently or more cleanly, but nothing is obviously broken in this code by itself.

Comment: Sorry. the issue is that the dropdown list not show the data.

Comment: I  edited the new code into the question. That's how we do it here... reading code in the comments is painful ;) What happens if you remove the Try/Catch?

Comment: Thank you. If i remove the try/catch in the class, the New ListItem in the "Select Country", "0") not show the text "select country" in the method.

Comment: I found some possible solutions to show item added from `ListItem` but I want you to include both DDL markup & `Page_Load` method, just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may helpful to you

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT CustomerId, Name FROM Customers")
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Connection = con
                con.Open()
                ddlCustomers.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                ddlCustomers.DataTextField = "Name"
                ddlCustomers.DataValueField = "CustomerId"
                ddlCustomers.DataBind()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
        ddlCustomers.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select Customer--", "0"))
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by modifying the connection string to:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="cnnPortalSmart" connectionString="server=XXXX;user id=XXXX;password=XXXXX!;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=XXXXX;SslMode=none" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```